# Why cant I access an object key within a function call

Tags: javascript, machine-learning

I am trying to access `color` from the `utils.styles` object by calling utils.styles within this function `graphics.drawPoint(ctx,pixelLoc, utils.styles[label].color);`

Code from Radu: No black box machine Learning

```
utils.styles={
    car:     { color:'gray',      text:'' },
    fish:    { color:'red',       text:'' },
    house:   { color:'yellow',    text:'' },
    tree:    { color:'green',     text:'' },
    bicycle: { color:'cyan',      text:'' },
    guiter:  { color:'blue',      text:'' },
    pencile: { color:'magenta',   text:'✏'  },
    clock:   { color:'lightgray', text:'⏲' }
}
```

```
for(const sample of samples) {
  const {point,label}=sample;
```

sample are collections of objects with labels as keys `['car','fish','house....'clock']` same as in `uitils.styles`

```
graphics.drawPoint(utils.styles[label].color);
```

This produces an error message: Uncaught TypeError:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'color')

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch

Comment: label must be something not available in `utils.styles`. Log label and checkl

Comment: Make sure your spelling is identical in the styles and the label, vis-a-vis "guiter" and "pencile" for example.